# Remote Desktop ActiveX control maximised

Tags: c#, winforms, remote-desktop, mstsc

In my application i am utilizing the [Remote Desktop ActiveX control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383022%28VS.85%29.aspx)

How do i maximize the RDP session? I would like it to be full screen once connected.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant I found that also but how do i use the property?

Comment: Can you provide a bit code of how you have implemented the RDP ActiveX control so better to help with the best way to set the property?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from your question if you're using this via the web or WinForms app but if it's from a WinForms application you can do the following.

First you need to subscribe to the OnConnected event

```
  // Subscribe to the OnConnected Event in the constructor or via the form designer.
  this.axMsRdpClient91.OnConnected += new System.EventHandler(this.axMsRdpClient91_OnConnected);


private void btnFullscreen_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
  if ( axMsRdpClient91.Connected == 0 )
  {

    axMsRdpClient91.UserName = "Username";
    axMsRdpClient91.Server = "address to server to connect to";
    // Connect to the server
    axMsRdpClient91.Connect();
  }

}
// When the the ActiveXControl raises the OnConnected event set the screen to full screen mode.
private void axMsRdpClient91_OnConnected( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
  ( (AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient9)sender ).FullScreen = true;
}
```